# While attaching current binding source error occurs: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I have created simple form for editing client list using Entity Framework and data binding. However, when im trying to edit rows error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" occurs. I don't know where I attach one object to two data contexts..

Main user control:

```
    ArtGalleryEntities db;

    public UserControl5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        db = new ArtGalleryEntities();
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        klienciBindingSource.DataSource = db.Klienci.ToList();

    }

    private void edit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (klienciBindingSource.Current == null)
            return;
        using (AddEditForm frm = new AddEditForm(klienciBindingSource.Current as Klienci))
        {
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                klienciBindingSource.DataSource = db.Klienci.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

AddEditForm here :

```
    ArtGalleryEntities db;

    public AddEditForm(Klienci obj)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        db = new ArtGalleryEntities();
        if (obj == null)
        {
            klienciBindingSource.DataSource = new Klienci();
            db.Klienci.Add(klienciBindingSource.Current as Klienci);

        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            klienciBindingSource.DataSource = obj;
            db.Klienci.Attach(klienciBindingSource.Current as Klienci); // here error occurs 

        }
    }
```

I have tried following replaces for attaching:

```
    db.Entry(klienciBindingSource.Current as Klienci).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
    db.Entry(klienciBindingSource.Current as Klienci).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

But it didn't work out for me

Comment: Read the error again. It explains what's wrong. You passed an entity from your main user control to `AddEditForm` and tried to save it using a *different* context. Don't use a new context in `AddEditForm` at all. Modify the object and call `SaveChanges` on the original context. That context is still in scope, in fact it's never disposed as long as the user control lives

Comment: If you need to create add a new object do so in `edit_button_Click`.

Comment: thanks, I will check that